# Serilization using newtonsoft json in c# unity3d

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, serialization, json.net

I have a class menctioned below and I am trying to serialize it with NewtonsoftJson

Example:

```
abcW = new ABCListWrapper();
abcW = getabcWDataObject();
string abcData = JsonUtility.ToJson(abcW);
```

if I use above line to serialize the object I am getting GameObject b, c data in serialized json string as something `"gameObject":{"instanceID":844016}"`.

```
abcW = new ABCListWrapper();
abcW = getabcWDataObject();
string abcData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(abcW);
```

if I use above lines to serialize the object I am **not getting** `GameObject b, c` data in serialized json string.

[Serializable]

```
public class ABC : ISerializable
{
    //SerializableDictionary source: http://www.jankowskimichal.pl/en/2010/10/serializabledictionary/

    public SerializableDictionary<int, ExampleClass> a = new SerializableDictionary<int, ExampleClass>();

    public GameObject b;

    public GameObject c;

    public bool d = false;

    public ABC e;

    public int f;

    public string g = "";

    public int h = -1;

    public int i = -1;

    public int j = -1;

    public string k = "default";

    public XYZ l = XYZ.P;
}

[Serializable]
public enum XYZ
{
    P,
    Q
}


[Serializable()]
public class ABCListWrapper : ISerializable
{

    public List<ABC> abcMappings = new List<ABC>();
    public string version = "1.53";
    public float interval;
}
```

How can I use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(abcW)` and make `GameObject b,c` data in in given object to contain in serialized object and I got while using `JsonUtility.ToJson()`. I have a complex object an I need to use the Newtonsoft to serialize and deserialize.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried a different JSON library? I have heard that Unity doesn't play nice with Newtonsoft.

Comment: Like could you suggest some examples

Comment: The Unity wiki suggests simpleJSON: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON